# Compound poisson distribution

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, compound-distributions

I'm trying to compute a maximum likelihood of compound Poisson gamma distribution in R. The distribution is defined by $ \sum_{j=1}^{N} Y_j $ where $Y_n$ is i.i.d sequence independent $\operatorname{gamma}(k,\theta)$ values and $N$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\beta$. I'm trying to estimate this parameters $\theta$ and $\beta$ without luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried EM? This is a latent variable model.

Comment: I used the optim() function, but that does not work!

Comment: You observed $Y_j$. $\theta$ and $\beta$ are unknown parameters you want to estimate. How about $N$ and $k$?

Comment: N is random variable of Poisson distribution and k is integer value.

Comment: N is observable or not observable? k is known parameter or unknown parameter?

Comment: Please add a minimal example  and explain what is wrong with the results